# Integrals of indicator functions question

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

I have a result

$\int_X \int_Y \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu]dP(y)dP(x) < a$

and I am trying to resolve the integral

$\int_X \int_Y \mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}] \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] dP(y)dP(x)$

From some previous work I can use Markov's inequality, $P[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}] < \frac{2 \sqrt{\epsilon}}{\mu}$

I only have a limited understanding of the relationship between integrals, indicator functions, and am trying to understand how to use the two results I have to get an upper bound on the integral in question.  I know (think) that $\int_X \mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}]dP(x) = P[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}$, and that the function of just $x$ should be constant w.r.t. the $Y$ integral, but how can I resolve this when one of my applicable results only goes halfway through the double integral and the other goes all the way through?

Comment: What is the relation between $g(x)$ and $g(x,y)$? Could be a typo?

Comment: I'm sorry, they're two totally different functions, will fix

Comment: Do you look for an upper bound or the equality?

Comment: Although practically, I didn't think it was relevant, but $h(x,y) = |g(x) - g(y)|$

Comment: Looking for an upper bound

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of an upper bound you're looking for.

Note that at least we have $\mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}]\leq 1$, so
\begin{align*}
&\int_X \int_Y \mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}] \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] dP(y)dP(x) \\
&\leq \int_X \int_Y \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] dP(y)dP(x)<a.
\end{align*}
If you want something sharper, then use Cauchy-Schwarz $(1)$, Jensen's (note that $x\mapsto x^{2}$ is convex) $(2)$, and then your given upper bounds that $(3)$, to get
\begin{align*}
&\int_X \int_Y \mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}] \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] dP(y)dP(x) \\
&=\int_X \mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}]\int_Y \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] dP(y)dP(x) \\
&\overset{(1)}{\leq} \Big(\int_X \mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}]^{2}\,dP(x)\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\Big(\int_Y \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] dP(y)\Big)^{2}dP(x)\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&\overset{(2)}{\leq} \Big(\int_X \mathbb{1}[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}]^{2}\,dP(x)\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\int_Y \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] ^{2}dP(y)dP(x)\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&=P[|f(x) - g(x)| > \frac{\mu}{2}]^{\frac{1}{2}}\Big(\int_Y \mathbb{1}[h(x,y) < \mu] dP(y)dP(x)\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&\overset{(3)}{\leq} \Big(\frac{2\sqrt{\varepsilon}}{\mu}\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{a}.
\end{align*}